# what should be the order of serverless plugins in serverless.yml file?

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I have read about the order of serverless plugins. for example, serverless-dynamodb-local must come before the serverless-offline plugin.

so, is the order of plugins necessary in the serverless.yml file?

how can I decide the order of my serverless plugins in the serverless.yml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plugins are loaded in order, from top to bottom. `serverless-offline` and `serverless-dynamodb-offline` are a special case because the former depends on the latter, but for the vast majority of plugins, this isn't an issue.

You can read more about it in the [documentation](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/google/guide/plugins#load-order).

Finally, I'd advise you to consider developing against the cloud, instead of using things like `severless-offline`. You can read my thesis on the subject [here](https://dev.to/aws-builders/developing-against-the-cloud-55o4).